# SharePoint Online list-formatting for Rich Text field

Tags: sharepoint, formatting

I am trying to implement a multiline view with view formatting for SharePoint Online Modern List, but am not able to quite get how to format a multiline rich text field. When I add the content, it prints out the entire html tags.

I was able to find this [article](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-list-formatting/issues/88) that says that it is not supported yet, but any help or other pointers to convert the html tags to plain text will work.

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to achieve this currently. I would suggest you use "plain text" in column settings. It is supporeted in json formatting.

[image].

Comment: Thanks Michael, this will be my last resort.